# How can I move the first word to the end?

Tags: java, string

> Enter a line of text. No punctuation please.
>   **Java is the language**
>   I have rephrased that line to read:
>   **Is the language Java**

This is an example, and I only know the char method, but I don't know how to move the first word to the end. which string method can I use?

Comment: And do you want the capitalization fixed as well?

Comment: When you say I know char method, do you mean you're only allowed char methods or that  you only know char methods? Btw is this java script?

Comment: yes， I want input a sentence and output is move the first word to the end...this is java and it need the String length?

Comment: Java!=JavaScript lol. we need to create a tag saying `Java!=JavaScript`, so that as soon as someone types Java they see that tag as well. And write appropriate tag.

Answer (score 5):

### What to do:

1. Split the sentence using
   String.split();
2. Create a List from the items
3. Reorder the List
4. Join the List items using a space

### Implementation in plain Java:

```
final String s = "Java Is The Language";
final List<String> list =
    new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+")));
list.add(list.size() - 1, list.remove(0));
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(final String word : list){
    if(sb.length() > 0){
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    sb.append(word);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

### Implementation using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/):

```
final String s = "Java Is The Language";
final List<String> list =
    Lists.newArrayList(Splitter
        .on(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE)
        .omitEmptyStrings()
        .split(s));
list.add(list.size() - 1, list.remove(0));
System.out.println(Joiner.on(' ').join(list));
```

Comment: I was about to answer this +1

Comment: @all hooray, 20k! Thanks everybody

Comment: @Roboson there's code here now. You can copy and paste it and probably complete your assignment. But if you want to learn something, follow the steps I outlined above and try to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you mean Java (and not JavaScript):

```
final String delimiter = " ";
String input = /* whatever */;
String[] tokens = input.split(delimiter);
String output = "";
for (int i = 1; i<tokens.length; i++)
{
    output += input[i] + delimiter;
}
output += tokens[0];
System.out.println(output);
```

Incidentally, this code could/would look very similar in JavaScript:

```
var delimiter = " ",
    input = /* whatever */,
    tokens = input.split(delimiter),
    output = [],
    len = tokens.length,
    i;

for (i = 1; i<len; i++)
{
    output.push(input[i]);
}
output.push(tokens[0]);
output = output.join(delimiter);
alert(output);
```

Comment: My bad. I thought you're printing array directly. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Substring, indexOf and length. Try those out.