# UpperCase problem, using IndexOf

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

Enter a line of text. No punctuation please.

Java is the language.

I have rephrased that line to read:

Is the language java.

Attempt:

```
 int x;
 String  sentence, first;

 System.out.println("\nEnter a line of text. No punctuation please.");

 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

 sentence=keyboard.nextLine();

   x = sentence.indexOf(" ");
 first= sentence.substring(0,x);
 second=sentence.substring(0,1)
 second=second.toUpperCase();  
 System.out.println("I have rephrased that line to read:");
 System.out.println(second+sentence.substring(x+1)+" "+first);
```

Output:

Enter a line of text. No punctuation please.

what is going on

I have rephrased that line to read:// It should read " Is going on what"

W s going on what

P.S -I need to make letter "i" capital.
     How can I make "second.substring(0,1)" read  character "i"?
     As suggested, I tried to figure out the stripping the letter and concatenating it 
     with   the uppercase but I am not sure.

To people lashing at me for not  doing this on my own. I have given it multiple attempts and read through the book. It was of no help. I had to ask the professor so he gave me a head start but still not sufficient. By all means, I want to understand it. Not everyone grasps the same way. I personally, need examples and   elaborate explanations to comprehend.

Comment: Why do they give so silly homework assignments nowadays?

Comment: Is this homework?  We like to tag questions that are homework related.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move the first word to the end?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796186/how-can-i-move-the-first-word-to-the-end)

Comment: (This is clearly homework.) The code you already have is very close. So close that if you understood the code you have, you wouldn't actually need to ask here. My suggestion is that you study the code you have, and understand it. The answer itself won't help you as much.

Comment: If your question was correctly answered you should mark that as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
   first= sentence.substring(0,4);
```

To:

```
   first= sentence.substring(0,x);
```

Then add:

```
   sentence = sentence.substring(x+1,sentence.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
first = sentence.substring (0, x);
// other stuff
System.out.println (sentence.substring (x + 1) + " " + first);
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use another call `substring` to strip the first part. See [the String class documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) and also [Manipulating Characters in a String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html)

---

Your code does not seem to be working at all. You save in `x` the position of the first space but don't use that, it should be `sentence.substring(0, x)`.

For the sentence: *how are you*. In `first` you'll have stored the first word: *how*

Then you should strip from `sentence` the first word with something like this: `sentence = sentence.substring(x+1)`. Now sentence will be: *are you*

After that just concatenate both:

```
String newSentence = sentence + " " + first;
```

And there you have stored in the variable `newSentence`: *are you how*

God bless!

Comment: Thank you for a concise explanation. But, I am still confused about  sentence.substring(x+1)?Okay never mind, I think I am starting get the point.

Comment: The String class doc i posted explains how it works. `x` will contain the position of the first white space. Then you add one to it to obtain the beginning of the 2nd word. `substring(x+1)` creates a new string beginning from the position supplied, which happens to be the beginning of the 2nd word, so you cut the first word out.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Another question:
How do I make letter y uppercase out of "you are how"? 
I tried "sentence.substring(0,1)" 
        "sentence=sentence.toUpperCase();"

It  didn't work.

Comment: See the string documentation I provided, I don't know Java API by heart. It should be something like UpperCase() or whatever. Oh and you can apply the same logic you used for removing the first word, but this time remove the first letter, uppercase it and then concatenate again.

Comment: Yeah, I tired doing that. I wasn't successful. Instead, I assigned a new string value to substring and tried to make it read the letter "i" then concatenated it. But that isn't working out too well either.It keeps reading the wrong character.